# Show that the Gelfand transform is a morphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

> Let $A$ be a commutative Banach algebra and let $x \in A$. We define the Gelfan transform of $x$ by $$\hat{x} (\chi)= \chi (x)$$ where $\chi$ is a nonzero multiplicative linear functional on $A$.

I need to show that $x \mapsto\hat{x}$ is a morphism, i.e if we define $$F(x)=\hat{x}$$ then we need to show that $$F(xy)= \hat{xy}=\hat{x}\hat{y}=F(x)F(y)$$

How can I go about showing this?

Comment: by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#Gelfand_representation_of_a_commutative_Banach_algebra) of characters

Answer (score 1):

Given a (nonzero) multiplicative linear functional $\chi$ on $A$ and $x,y\in A$, we have
\begin{align*}
\hat{xy}(\chi)&=\chi(xy)=\chi(x)\chi(y)=\hat{x}(\chi)\hat{y}(\chi) \\
\hat{(x+y)}(\chi)&=\chi(x+y)=\chi(x)+\chi(y)=\hat{x}(\chi)+\hat{y}(\chi)
\end{align*}
Furthermore, for any scalar $\alpha$, we have
$$ \hat{(\alpha x)}(\chi)=\chi(\alpha x)=\alpha\chi(x)=a\hat{x}(\chi) $$

Since $\chi$ was arbitrary, we see that
$$F(xy)=F(x)F(y),\qquad F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y), \qquad F(\alpha x)=\alpha F(x).$$

Comment: Thank you! :). I have not shown it to be linear yet. Can you please show that to me as well? I really appreciate it

Comment: @user229672 Does that help?

Comment: That certainly does! :). Thank you! Do you please mind explaining to me (in a comment will be fine) why we needed to show linearity as well? :).

Comment: @user229672 The Gelfand transform is a morphism of *algebras*, which have both linear and multiplicative structures.  To be a morphsim of algebras, you must preserve both of these.

Comment: Thank you! :). This makes perfect sense! :)

Comment: @user229672 Glad to help!